# codeigniter insert into table with condition

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a form input:

```html
<div class="row" id="form_pesan">
                
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" />

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg typeahead typeahead_user_email" autocomplete="off" id="user_email"  name="user_email"  placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="phone"  name="phone"  placeholder="Phone" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="plate_number"  name="plate_number"  placeholder="Plate Number" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="location_name" name="location_name">
                        <?php foreach ($vendor as $v) { 
                            ?>
                            <option id="<?php echo $v['location_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $v['location_id']?>" ><?php echo $v['name'] ;?></option>
                        <?php }; ?> 
                        </select>
                    </div>
                
                </div>
<button id="add" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick=add()>Add</button>
```

Javascript function add():

```js
function add(){
    var formIsValid = true;
      $(matchFormFields).each(function() {
        $(this).css('border-color', '');
        if(!$.trim($(this).val())) {
          $(this).css('border-color', errorColor);
          formIsValid = false;
        }
    });
    if (formIsValid) {
    user_email = $("#user_email").val();
    phone = $("#phone").val();
    plate_number = $("#plate_number").val(); 
    location_id = $('#location_name option:selected').attr('id');

    $.ajax
        ({
            url : "<?php echo site_url('admin/add_driver')?>/",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{user_email: user_email, plate_number: plate_number, location_id: location_id},
            success: function(data)
            {     
                $("#add_driver_modal").modal("hide");
                $("#alert").show();
                console.log(user_email);
                console.log(phone);
                console.log(plate_number);
                console.log(location_name);
                //location.reload();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error data');
            }

        });
    };
 }
```

The controller :

```
public function add_driver()
{
    if(!$this->user_permission->check_permission())return;

        $phone                      =   $this->input->post('phone');
        $user_email                 =   $this->input->post('user_email');
        $user_password              =   "tiki1234";
        $plate_number               =   $this->input->post('plate_number');
        $location_id                =   $this->input->post('location_id');

        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('user');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $data['user'] = $query->result_array();
        foreach ($data['user'] as $u) {
            if($user_email == $u['user_email']){
                $data_user_driver = array(
                    'user_id'                   => $u['user_id'],
                    'plate_number'              => $plate_number,
                    'location_id'               => $location_id,
                    'current_lat'               => 0,
                    'current_lon'               => 0
                );
                $this->db->insert('user_driver', $data_user_driver); 
            }
            else{
                $this->load->library('login_library');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');

                $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'Email is already in use');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[user.user_email]|max_length[255]');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_password', 'Password', 'trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[32]|callback__password_valid');
                $this->form_validation->run();
                $this->login_library->register($user_email, $user_password);

                if ($this->form_validation->run() && $data = $this->login_library->register($user_email, $user_password)) {
                    if (isset($data['success']) && $data['success'] == TRUE) {
                        echo json_encode((array('success' => 1, "msg" => $data['message'])));
                    } else
                        echo json_encode(array('success' => 0, "msg" => $data["message"]));
                } else
                    echo json_encode(array('success' => 0, "msg" => validation_errors()));
                }
            }               
}
```

Th condition is, if the `input->post->('user_email')` doesn't exist in `user` table, then insert into `user` table first then `user_driver` table, if it exist, then insert into `user_driver` only.

The values are inserting into database but it throws an error `duplicate entry ****@gmail.com for key user_email_unique`

Comment: What's the use of `register` action?

Comment: i am using `register` library to add driver as a new user. @RameshKumar

Comment: remove below line before if condition and then try. `$this->login_library->register($user_email, $user_password);`  Hope it will work for you. One more thing. You may load library outside loop else that impact the loading time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] I missed the `where` syntax in SQL, I could use it to check whether the variable is match the value in the table :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by first selecting the data from the table by the email id as follows:

```
$user_array = $this->db->where('user_email',$this->input->post('user_email')->get('users')->row_array();
if(count($user_array)>0){
$this->db->update('users',$update_array,array('user_email',$this->input->post('user_email'))); //update driver by email
}else{
 $this->db->insert('users',$data_user_driver); //insert the data
}
```

Comment: in case you may misunderstand my question, I want to insert new id, email ,and etc into `user` table if `input->post->('user_email`)` doesn't match the  value in `user` table, **after inserting into** `user`, i want it to insert into `user_driver` as well, but if the `input->post->('user_email)` exist in `user` table, then it will **insert only into** `user_driver` table. As far as i understand your answer, why do I need the `this->db->update('users')`? please help me understand it :)

Comment: ok then you can insert the new record and use update query globally.